# Reset Page On Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridjs

I don't want to reset the page after an update. Specifically, when using `forceUpdate()`, I want my grid to only update the data at the current pagination.

```
pagination: {
      enabled: true,
      limit: 25,
      summary: false,
      resetPageOnUpdate: false,
    },
```

I see in pagination there is a `resetPageOnUpdate` attribute, but when I use `forceUpdate()` it doesn't seem to work and still resets the internal partition. Help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- I am not good at writing English. Consider it and see.
- I use jquery

$(".gridjs-currentPage").text() : current page number

update before save current page data

```
.updateConfig({
     update data...
     pagination: {
            setting... ,
            page : current page number - 1
     }
}).forceRender();
```